# Symfony 4 Flex Database connection using `urlencode`

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I am starting a new project using Symfony 4 + Flex. At this time I'm trying to connect my new app to a MySQL database.

I'm following the [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database), and I have already add `doctrine` to my dependencies :

```
composer require doctrine
composer require maker --dev
```

Then I've added the database connection information in the environment variable `DATABASE_URL` defined inside `.env` like this :

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
DATABASE_URL=mysql://myUser:myPasswordWithSpecialChars@127.0.0.1:3306/myDbName
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

At this point I am facing an issue :

> DBALException
>
> Malformed parameter "url".

I'm thinking this is caused by the fact that my MySQL password is using some special characters. The documentation is talking about it :

> If the username, password or database name contain any character considered special in a URI (such as !, @, $, #), you must encode them. See RFC 3986 for the full list of reserved characters or use the urlencode function to encode them.

I don't really understand how or where to use the [urlencode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function because the `.env` file is not a PHP one (as `doctrine.yaml`).

Is someone have already use the `urlencode` function to encode a MySQL password containing special chars ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is my `doctrine.yaml` file :

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8
            collate: utf8_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

I've not edited the database url parameter because it is already defined in `.env`. Am I right ?

Comment: Can you show your .env file please?

Comment: Can you also show doctrine.yaml file?

Comment: Have you tried to encapsulate the password in quotes `'`?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri, I've edited the question with the `.env` doctrine configuration part, and the `doctrine.yaml` file.

Comment: @JackSkeletron yes I have tried to put quotes around it, with no success.

Comment: So try to encode your password with urlencode and paste it into the env variable. I mean, encode it with a php script and copy the result to paste.

Comment: OK, I will try this, you must be right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to change this:

```
url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

to this:

```
url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Comment: I have encoded the password with `urlencode` function in a php script apart, and I've copied the output directly in the environment variable, like Jack Skeletron said in the comments.
And with this change in `doctrine.yaml` everything is OK. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you @ClémentCanuto

Comment: The reason for the behavior of the Symfony resolve function is documented here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/env_var_processors.html#built-in-environment-variable-processors
If DATABASE_URL contains pairs of percent signs, like %foo%, it treats it as a container and will try to replace it with a variable from the YAML file.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still searching to solve this issue here you are the steps:

1- use `urlencode('SC8uk#ccj59c%DQbpb8S^9&JbJ')` in a new PHP file and get the result which is a string and paste it like this:

`###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ### DATABASE_URL='mysql://root:SC8uk%23ccj59c%25DQbpb8S%5E9%26JbJ@127.0.0.1:3306/app?serverVersion=8.0.32&charset=utf8mb4' ###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###`

2- open this file projectDirectory > config > packages > doctrine.yaml

Then edit this
`url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'`

to
`url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'`

3- open your terminal use this command to create your database
`bin/console doctrine:database:create`

Finaly, Database created. Enjoy